# How to make a navigationbar that contains custom Components with Material UI and React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui

I am trying to use the BottomNavigation from Material UI. However, instead of showing lables and text I want to use custom-made ImageButtons components.

I have the following code from Material UI:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import BottomNavigation from '@material-ui/core/BottomNavigation';
import ImageButton from '.././buttons/ImageButton';

const useStyles = makeStyles({
    root: {
        width: 1200,
    },
});

export default function CreateProjectNavigation() {
    const classes = useStyles();
    const [value, setValue] = React.useState(0);

    return (
        <BottomNavigation
            value={value}
            onChange={(event, newValue) => {
                setValue(newValue);
            }}
            showLabels
            className={classes.root}
        >
            <ImageButton buttonNr="1" text="Project Details" />
            <ImageButton buttonNr="2" text="Types/Discipline" />
            <ImageButton buttonNr="3" text="Fieldwork" />
            <ImageButton buttonNr="4" text="Personell and Institutions" />
            <ImageButton buttonNr="5" text="Summary" />
        </BottomNavigation>
    );
}
```

And here is the code for the ImageButton:

```
import React from 'react';
import { makeStyles } from '@material-ui/core/styles';
import EditIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Edit';
import MenuBookIcon from '@material-ui/icons/MenuBook';
import RoomIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Room';
import PeopleIcon from '@material-ui/icons/People';
import DoneIcon from '@material-ui/icons/Done';
import Button from '@material-ui/core/Button';
import Grid from '@material-ui/core/Grid';

const useStyles = makeStyles(theme => ({
    root: {
        margin: theme.spacing(1),
        borderRadius: '50%',
        height: '75px',
        width: '75px',
        '&$disabled': {
            backgroundColor: '#0af7ff',
            color: '#000000',
        },
    },
    disabled: {},
}));

export default function ImageButton({ active, buttonNr, text, handler, link }) {
    let icon;
    const classes = useStyles();

    switch (buttonNr) {
        case '1':
            icon = <EditIcon />;
            break;
        case '2':
            icon = <MenuBookIcon />;
            break;
        case '3':
            icon = <RoomIcon />;
            break;
        case '4':
            icon = <PeopleIcon />;
            break;
        case '5':
            icon = <DoneIcon />;
            break;
        default:
            break;
    }

    return (
        <Grid container direction="column" justify="" alignItems="center">
            <Button
                variant="contained"
                classes={{
                    root: classes.root,
                    disabled: classes.disabled,
                }}
                disabled={active}
                onClick={handler}
                href={link}
            >
                {icon}
            </Button>
            <p>
                <b>{text}</b>
            </p>
        </Grid>
    );
}
```

Unfortunately, the ImageButton turns out really disorted and wrong in the BottomNavigation bar. Additionally, the text below the image button just appears next to the button instead of under the moment it is placed in the BottomNavigation.

Does anyone have an idea on what to do about this?

Comment: I would suggest two things to try here. 1. Try using a `<div style={ { display: 'flex', flexDirection: 'column' } }>` as a wrapper instead of `Grid`. 2. Try using `IconButton` instead of `Button` for your icons.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure, but I think you need to wrap your buttons inside `BottomNavigationAction` component for `BottomNavigation`. `BottomNavigationAction` has *component* props. Maybe you should to pass your buttons inside this props, because children prop is unsupported for `BottomnavigationAction` component.
Here you can see API details https://material-ui.com/api/bottom-navigation-action/